# Доступ к элементу массива по ключу из переменной

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Дано:

```
$column = array(
    'value_1' => 'on',
    'value_2' => 'on',
    'value_3' => 'off'
);

$values= array('value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3');
```

Неработающий пример:

```
{% for value in values %}
    <input type="checkbox" {% if column.{{value}} == 'on' %}checked{% endif %}>
{% endfor %}
```

Вопрос в том, как подставить в условие переменную `{{value}}`? Может что-то вроде `column.{value}`, `column.[value]`, `column.'value'`? Но это все не работает. Как реализовать?

Comment: ``{{ column[value] }}`` пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а почему вы обращаетесь к элементу массива через точку `column.{{value}}`?

Попробуйте такой вариант ...

```
{% for value in values %}
    <input type="checkbox" {% if column[value] == 'on' %}checked{% endif %}>
{% endfor %}
```

Также попробуйте такой вариант

```
{% for value in values %}
    <input type="checkbox" {{ column[value] == 'on' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Это подходит. Спасибо.

Comment: а в чем принципиальная разница в точке и скобках, ведь в традиционных случаях и то и то работает (по крайней мере с массивами)

Comment: В том что скобочки работают для твоего случая, а точка - нет.

Comment: Я имею ввиду с точки зрения начинки Twig. Просто любопытно.

Answer (score 2):

Все намного проще. Для доступа к ключу массива можно использовать синтаксис с квадратными скобками:

```
{% for value in values %}
    <input type="checkbox" {% if column[value] == 'on' %}checked{% endif %}>
{% endfor %}
```

А вот и [рабочий TWIGFiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/mu4cet) с примером.